# Are there any Cons for PHP redirect, as it seems major websites choose to use Javascript Redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, http-redirect

I've took a look at the source codes of the redirect pages of about 5 big websites (that do redirects to their sponsors).

About 4 of them were using these various Javascript redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.location = 'http://www.destination.com'; 
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout( function() {
window.location.replace('http://www.destination.com');
}, 1200);
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { 
setTimeout(function () { 
Redirect(); 
}, 1500) 
}); 

function Redirect() { 
window.location = $('#redirect-to').val(); 
} 
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.location.href='http://www.destination.com'
</script>
```

And one was using HTTP META REFRESH:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0;URL="http://www.destination.com"' />
```

**The question:**

Since I know that PHP, and in particular redirect such as:

```
header( "refresh:0;url=http://www.destination.com" );
```

Are "invisible" in the source code, I wonder:

1. Is there a way to tell if PHP redirects were also being used simultaneously on these page?
2. since the above codes were present - do you think PHP redirects were being used? could it be that these codes are just "fallback" in case the PHP didn't work?
3. If so, why would a fallback be needed, what can go wrong with such a simple PHP redirect?
4. If not, then why the web deveploper chose to use JS/META REFRESH over PHP? are there any cons to PHP compared to JS/META?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I don't think that including a delay in the redirect, showing content, or running various scripts while doing the redirect, can serve as a motive for using JS/META over PHP, since this can be done in PHP as well, with this code for example:

```
<?php 
header( "refresh:10;url=http://www.domain.com" );
?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Redirecting you.
<script type="text/javascript">code</script><noscript>code</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my opinion php redirects (or .htaccess) are better since they are more reliable, if the user has javascript turned off it means no redirect. Also 5 websites does not count as "most" test at least 20.

Comment: Well, these websites rank in the first page on Google for their main keywords, so I think they certainly can be used as a good example that would raise these questions

Comment: Popularity is rarely linked to quality.

Comment: Javascript redirect is triggered at client side, sometimes due to some event. And without receiving redirect header from server. For my site, I will use js redirect and PHP header as failsafe.

Comment: @Quentin I'm just reasonably assuming that if these websites have the thorough understanding of how to achieve #1-#5 spots on Google, they would have the same understanding about using the best method for redirecting.

Comment: I wouldn't call that assumption "reasonable". There are lots of factors involved in being high up on Google, mostly based about what the site says and not how well its code is written.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really such a thing as a PHP redirect. There is an HTTP redirect, which you can send to the browser using PHP (and numerous other techniques).

> Is there a way to tell if PHP redirects were also being used simultaneously on these page?

Unless you are using a tool which explicitly ignores HTTP redirects (and you'd know if you were), then you would see the redirected resource and not the original.

> since the above codes were present - do you think PHP redirects were being used? could it be that these codes are just "fallback" in case the PHP didn't work?

No

> If so, why would a fallback be needed, what can go wrong with such a simple PHP redirect?

Short of the URL being wrong, nothing can go wrong.

> If not, then why the web deveploper chose to use JS/META REFRESH over PHP? are there any cons to PHP compared to JS/META?

The only reasons I can think of for using a document level redirect are:

- To do the redirect on a time delay and show the user a message first
- To run JavaScript in the document (e.g. to harvest information about the browser) and send it to the server before or while redirecting.

Comment: But it IS possible to create a PHP "redirect" page that would both have a time delay, and run Javascript and other content show up on the page. I can give you an example for such code if you want.